# Programmatically remove all permissions of a file

Tags: c++, qt

On Linux, `chmod` can set the permissions of a given file to `none`, ie. no one can `read/write/exec` this file.
([Wikipedia - Octal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes))

How to do the same with Qt?
I know there is [`QFile::setPermissions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#setPermissions) and [`enum QFile::Permission`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#Permission-enum), but in the enum there is no value `none`.

Comment: Have you tried `QFile::setPermissions(0)`, this should mean "none".

Comment: Note: From the documentation of 'Permissions: "Warning: Because of differences in the platforms supported by Qt, the semantics of ReadUser, WriteUser and ExeUser are platform-dependent: On Unix, the rights of the owner of the file are returned and on Windows the rights of the current user are returned. This behavior might change in a future Qt version."

Answer (score 4):

`QFile::setPermissions(0)` clears all permissions as it does `chmod` on Linux.

---

Update for Windows

According to Qt [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) documentation:

> Qt's understanding of file permissions is limited, which affects
>   especially the `QFile::setPermissions()` function. On Windows, Qt will
>   set **only the legacy read-only flag**, and that only when none of the
>   Write* flags are passed. Qt does not manipulate access control lists
>   (ACLs), which makes this function mostly useless for NTFS volumes. It
>   may still be of use for USB sticks that use VFAT file systems. POSIX
>   ACLs are not manipulated, either.

So, on Windows it is possible to set or unset legacy read-only flag using `QFile::setPermissions()`.
Usage of that feature is also tricky. To set the read-only flag only some `Read* permission should be configured. However, to remove that flag a write permission should be added, for example:

```
// set Windows read-only file flag
file.setPermissions(QFile::ReadOther);
// remove Windows read-only file flag
file.setPermissions(QFile::ReadOther | QFile::WriteOther);
```

The last trick I found in the answer to [Qt C++ remove a read only file in windows using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504225/qt-c-remove-a-read-only-file-in-windows-using)

Comment: Check this out: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265675/is-it-ok-to-take-someone-elses-comment-and-post-it-as-your-own-answer ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 sorry, however you did not post an answer. I verified that it works on Linux before your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You say it works on Linux, but what about Windows? I've tried it on Windows, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @gpalex In Windows it is much harder, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021645/qt-setpermissions-not-setting-permisions
QFile::setPermissions() does not manipulate ACLs.
There is a thread regarding issues of cross platform file permissions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform. Unfortunately there is no simple solution for Windows NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Permissions` is just a typedef for `QFlags<Permission>`, you can use the constructor `QFlags<Permission>(Zero zero = 0)` thus:

```
file.setPermissions(Permissions());
```

or - in C++ 11:

```
file.setPermissions({});
```